# XML syntax folding and custom tag spell checking

Tags: folding, spell-checking, filetype-xml

I have the following in my `~/vim/syntax/xrc.vim` to spell check contents of specific tags when editing XRC files that are just XML files with predefined schema:

```
runtime syntax/xml.vim

" check spelling for the user-visible strings.
syn region xrcString matchgroup=xmlTagName start="<\z(label\|text\|tooltip\|value\)>" end="</\z1>" contains=xmlEntity,@Spell

" and also highlight them as such.
hi link xrcString xmlString
```

and it works without problems -- as long as I don't also try doing `let g:xml_syntax_folding=1`.

If I enable syntax folding for XML, my region definition is not taken into account any longer (at least not with Vim 8.2). It seems to be due to the different `xmlRegion` definition in this case in Vim own `syntax/xml.vim`, but I'm not really sure.

Ideally I'd like to have both folding and spell checking for my tags. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like xmlRegion is only defined when g:xml_syntax_folding and this prevents matching of your syntax group. Please open an issue at the upstream repository https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/

Comment: BTW: I cannot reproduce this with the latest runtime files from there

Comment: Thanks Christian, I'll try to recheck this with the latest version from there, sorry for not thinking to do it before asking.

Comment: Sorry for the much longer than planned delay, but I finally rechecked this with the latest version and I don't think it changes anything, so I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/issues/23). Thanks again!

Comment: will have a look soon